# ansible: handler not fired

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

My playbook

```
---
- name: Nuovo server GV
  gather_facts: no
  hosts:
    - new-gv.vm
  roles:
    - ssh_configuration
  handlers:
    - name: Restart sshd
      service:
        name: sshd
        state: restarted
```

In the `ssh_configuration` tasks file there is this

```
- name: Setup alternate SSH port
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    regexp: "^Port"
    line: "Port {{ configured_port }}"
  notify:
    - Restart sshd
```

The problem is that Restart sshd is NOT executed.

I tried and retried a lot of times a clean restart and I am sure: the addition of the "Port 1122" line is added into remote host file.

I ask you how to diagnose the problem, I cannot understand if handler is not fired or is broken for some reason.

I also tried adding

```
- name: Ensure SSH is reloaded if need be
  meta: flush_handlers
```

In the `-vvvv` mode I can see ONLY

```
META: ran handlers
```

But I expected a section "RUN HANDLER", if I am not remembering wrong

> I'm sure this is not an Ansible Bug, it's only due to my inexperience

Comment: Have you tried to add the handler to the role's handlers?

Comment: @realtebo why the handlers is not handled inside the role?

Comment: ah, sorry for that, misread that on my side. You can use handlers from a role in a play but not the other way.

Comment: What happened when you ran the playbook with the handler properly in the role? Please show the output.

Comment: @realtebo Please remove the `include_tasks` step. It is not needed. I think you are mixing up scopes here. What you are trying is to use a handler from a play in a role, which won't work. However you can use a handler from a role in a play where you are using that role.

Comment: @HenrikPingel: i solved, so moved edited part into an indipendent new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed handler definition from play book.

I created `/roles/ssh_configuration/handlers/main.yml`:

```
- name: Restart sshd
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

Changed playbook in

```
---
- name: Nuovo server GV
  gather_facts: no
  hosts:
    - new-gv.vm
  roles:
    - ssh_configuration
  handlers:
    - include_tasks: roles/ssh_configuration/handlers/main.yml
```

*this works*

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the handler is defined in the `playbook` when it should have been defined in the role. Place

```
- name: Restart sshd
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

inside `roles/ssh_configuration/handlers/main.yml` and it should work.

Comment: Nothing changed !